# CORS axios request does not resolve cookie

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, axios, cross-domain

i already had this problem before, but i fixed it with all the configuration detailed in previous requests about this problem by other people.

postman does recive the cookie i send , and the browser does not

// axios config from front

```
const axios = Axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,

});
```

```
const res = await axios({
 url: `${BASE_URL}${endpoint}`,
      method,
      data,
      params: method === "GET" ? data : null,
    });
```

// CORS options config

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Express serve static files on production environment
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "public")));
} else {
  // Configuring CORS
  const corsOptions = {
    // Make sure origin contains the url your frontend is running on
    origin: [
      "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
      "http://localhost:5173",
      "http://127.0.0.1:5173",
      "http://localhost:5174",
      "http://127.0.0.1:5174",
      "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
      "http://localhost:3030",
      "http://localhost:3000",
    ],
    credentials: true,
  };
  app.use(cors(corsOptions));
}
```

// cookie config

```
const loginToken = authService.getLoginToken(user)
res.cookie('loginToken', loginToken, {sameSite: 'None', secure: true})
```

now login token do appear on my postman request but browser do no get it...im banging my head now for hours .. any idea gods of code?

Comment: `secure: true` - are you really running over HTTPS?

Comment: no, but i did tried with secure and without it

Comment: I don’t know of this is the case, but if there is a cookie set in the past with the secure flag, Chrome does not allow you to set a new cookie without the secure  flag. You might not see the old cookie (due to the different url, http vs https) and Chrome will not show an error (afaik). Firefox will show an error that the cookie can’t be replaced.